# XML external entity: get data by url

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

How do you get data via http?

I got error 'Error: Entity 'bar' not defined'. If I use local txt file it works good

```js
var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
var xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <!DOCTYPE foo [
           <!ELEMENT foo ANY>
            <!ENTITY bar SYSTEM "https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt"> 
        ]>
        <foo>&bar;</foo>`;

var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xml, {
    noblanks: true,
    noent: true,
    nocdata: true
});

var foo = xmlDoc.get('//foo');

console.log(foo.text());
```

Comment: And you checked and asked over on https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs already?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I will ask, thanks